# The usefullness / reasoning of catch (...)

Tags: c++, exception

Even though C++ does not mandate it, the common practice is to derive exception objects from `std::exception` or one of its subclasses.
The only exception (pun not intended) that I am aware of are `boost::thread_interrupted`.
(`std::nested_exception` is supposed to be used as a mix-in rather than thrown directly).

In addition, `catch (...)` cannot provide any information on the exception that it caught.

Given that, what are the reasons (if any) to use `catch (...)` instead of, or in addition to, `catch (std::exception const&)` in new code?

Comment: Maybe consider what happens if during a destructor invocation, some code you didn't write gets called and throws an exception you were not aware of.  Unhandled exceptions during a destructor will cause your program to terminate.  Using `catch(...)` prevents this (of course, it is wise to investigate the reason for the thrown exception, but at least your program didn't die).

Comment: good practice does not mean that it is guarnateed. The only safe way to catch really all excpetions is to `catch(...)`. You never know who did `throw 42;` or similar

Comment: reading between the lines it appears as if you are talking about you writing both the `throw` and the `catch`. More common is that you call `foo` from a library written by someone. In the worst case you dont know what `foo` might throw. And as Paul mentioned there are cases where you want to make 100% sure to catch any exception

Comment: There might be uses-cases where one just want to know if an exception happened or not, but it doesn't really matter what the exception might be

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ignoring the question of whether this really is "common practice" in real programs ([Qt disagrees](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qexception.html)), the point of `catch(...)` is to do cleanup work that does not require interacting with the exception itself.

The common idiom today is to encapsulate such cleanup logic into the destructors of RAII objects that live on the stack. Where such things cannot be easily done, `catch(...)` serves as a viable alternative, so long as you `throw;` at the end.

But `catch(...)` is also useful for forwarding exceptions in non-local ways. For example, if you're writing a thread-pool, if an exception escapes the "main" function of a task function, you need to capture it and forward it to the person waiting on the task. This is done using `catch(...)` and [`current_exception()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/current_exception):

```
try
{
  my_task.set_value(std::invoke(task_func, params));
}
catch(...)
{
  //Captures the exception and forwards it to the task.
  my_task.exception(std::current_exception());
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't `std::current_exception()` forwarding work in any `catch` clause?

Comment: @AlexO: It would work, but you wouldn't be able to catch *every* exception.

Comment: It might be also worth noting that catch(...) also can handle unwinding that isn't a C++ exception. e.g. forced_unwind where current_exception may be null.

Comment: @JeffGarrett, can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 7):

`catch(...)` can be used when you want to capture the exception to handle it later via [`std::current_exception`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/current_exception). For example, if an error occurs in a worker thread, you might want the thread that scheduled the task to handle the exception and not the worker thread.

It can be used when you intend to immediately rethrow the exception, but want to run some code before you do. You can call `throw;` after your code in the `catch(...)` exception handler to rethrow whatever exception was caught after you're done.

It can be used when you don't know what exceptions a function might throw (maybe you are using a poorly documented library). It lets you know something went wrong, even if you don't know exactly what. Whether or not this is better than terminating depends on the context.

It can be used to be 100% sure you catch anything. For example, if you are writing a library which uses a C compatible API, you have to translate exceptions to something C understands like error codes. You can use `catch(...)` as a final handler to report some "unknown error" error code and insure no exceptions leak from the function.

There are a lot of use cases for `catch(...)`, whether it is because you want to write generic code which doesn't specifically care right away about the exception type, or as a way to work around the absence of constraints on what type of object a function can throw.